# Multiple readings from csv - python scraping

Tags: python, instagram, screen-scraping

I've the next code:

```
from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile

PROFILE="instagram_user"

L = Instaloader()
profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)

print(profile.followers)
```

I would like to pass multiple users through csv and the script would run for each user.

Thanks.

Comment: Make that a function with profile as a parameter. Now you can use `csv` or maybe even `pandas` to read the csv file and call the function. For what you are doing now, `csv` is fine.

Comment: Could you put the code? I took this code from the Internet. Thanks

Comment: and that the script runs with all the users that I pass through csv

Comment: Stackoverflow is for helping with bugs, not writing the program itself. Feel free to come back with issues during implementation but you'll have to go elsewhere for the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've the next (this is another file in bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r user
do
    sed -i '/PROFILE/ s/="[^"][^"]*"/="{$user}"/' webscraping.py
    python3 webscraping.py >> scraping.txt
done < users.csv
```

I would like to remplace the username (with the users that are in the csv) in the webscraping.py and then run the script and saving every pass into a .txt

But that's not working. This literally puts the value "{$user}" in the PROFILE variable of the webscraping.py file (and not the csv users).